# Grouping items with even distribution in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, data-structures

Consider a student table with 104 rows in it. I need to create groups with a minimum of 10 students in each groups. In the case with 104 students, I would end up having 10 groups of 10 students and 1 group of 4 students if I iterate on each students and create the grouping. There's a rule that a group with remaining students cannot have less than 5 students in it (in this case the last group consist of 4 student). Two possible approach I'm trying to do:

1. Roll up the last group that has less than 5 students and assign each of them to any groups, or
2. Spread the last group evenly to any groups.

How do I achieve any of these? Many thanks.

Eric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ntile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx).

> Distributes the rows in an ordered partition into a specified number
> of groups. The groups are numbered, starting at one. For each row,
> NTILE returns the number of the group to which the row belongs.

Some sample code:

```
declare @NumberOfStudents int
declare @StudentsPerGroup int

set @StudentsPerGroup = 10
set @NumberOfStudents = 104

select StudentID,
       ntile(@NumberOfStudents / @StudentsPerGroup) over(order by StudentID) as GroupID
from Students
```

Try it out on [SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/64276/ntile).

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work correctly according to requirement *There's also a constrain that a group cannot have less than 5 students in it*. Also for a hundert students there will be eleven groups.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović - The requirement was that no group should have more than 10 students and no less than 5 students. This will create 11 groups evenly with 10 students in some groups and 9 students in some. As I understand the question this should do what he wants.

Comment: I got it wrong. I thought that he wanted to create groups of ten and distribute surplus evenly, but it was just my imagination.

Comment: Thanks guys. Actually Nikola was right. It's my mistake. I should have been more clear. Thanks for the help

Comment: I took out +1 in 'ntile((@NumberOfStudents / @StudentsPerGroup)+1)' and I got exactly what I need.

Comment: @Eric - Ok, that will give you groups with 10 or 11 students when you have a total of 104 students.

Comment: @Mikael - I posted another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779757/partitioning-by-counts-in-sql) related to this. Perhaps you could help? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variant 2. First part prepares counters. As I don't have any data on students I resolved to creating a temporary table of @maxStudents rows with only one column ID.

First cte (students) generates a list of students of maxStudents rows. Second (s) extracts students assigning them row number (obviously not necessary here, but essential when you plug in your query that retrieves students). It also returns number of students.

Third part places students into groups. Students belonging to last group will be relocated to another group if they belong to last group having less than @minGroupSize members. Version one can be achieved by replacing then part in case statement with for example 1 to place them in group one.

```
declare @group_size int
set @group_size = 10
declare @maxStudents int
set @maxStudents = 104
declare @minGroupSize int
set @minGroupSize = 5

;with students as (
     select 1 id
     union all
     select 2 * id + b
          from students cross join (select 0 b union all select 1) b
          where 2 * id + b <= @maxStudents
),
s as (
    select students.id, row_number() over(order by students.id) - 1 rowNumber, count (*) over () TotalStudents
      from students
)
select s.id StudentID, 
       case when TotalStudents % @group_size < @minGroupSize
                 and rowNumber >= (TotalStudents / @group_size * @group_size)
            then rowNumber - (TotalStudents / @group_size * @group_size)
            else rowNumber / @group_size
            end + 1 Group_number
  from s
  order by 2, 1
```

Comment: is possible to use ntile on this case?