# Partitioning by counts in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, data-structures

This issue is related to question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734280/grouping-items-with-even-distribution-in-sql). I have a table that looks like this:

```
Item    Count
1       1
2       4
3       8
4       2
5       6
6       3
```

I need to group items that are, for example, less than 5 into a new group and the total of each groups should be at least 5. The result should look like this:

```
Item    Group   Count  
1       1       1
2       1       4
3       2       8
4       3       2
5       4       6
6       3       3
```

How do I achieve this? Many thanks.

Comment: How dynamic does this need to be? Are you just going to have groups 1 and 2, or are there going to be a number of groups that scales with the data set?

Comment: Actually the number of groups created would depend on the constrain. On the sample above, I use 5. Our end user could enter any range of numbers.

Comment: My first thought is to use APPLY with a UDF but an elegant rowset-based solution may not be feasible. Might be easier to use a multi-statement UDF or a proc.

Comment: what happens if the count is 3 where item is 2 and there is a item 7 where the item is 1 ? Does that item 7 become group 1 or group 5 ?

Answer (score 2):

Why isn't this a correct result?

```
Item    Group   Count  
1       1       1
2       2       4
3       3       8
4       4       2
5       5       6
6       1       3
```

Or this?

```
Item    Group   Count  
1       1       1
2       2       4
3       3       8
4       4       2
5       5       6
6       6       3
```

Seems to me that you're trying to solve the answer 'how to group the items as to minimize the number of groups and maximize the number of items in each group, w/o exceeding the limit 5'. Which sounds a lot like the [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). Perhaps a you should read the [Celko's SQL Stumper: The Class Scheduling Problem](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/celkos-sql-stumper-the-class-scheduling-problem/) and the solutions proposed. Others have also approached this problem, eg. [And now for a completely inappropriate use of SQL Server](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2011/02/22/and-now-for-a-completely-inappropriate-use-of-sql-server/). Heads up: this is no a trivial problem by any means. Any naive algorithm will die a slow death attempting to solve it on a 1M rows table...

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. In the sample above, the minimum number of items in each group is 5. So if a group has less than 5 items, it should be distributed to other groups. I'm not sure what's the impact on the performace but I'm expecting less than 100K rows per process